# I need help finding an error in my installation

Tags: wordpress, error

I am mostly finished with moving our website from a Joomla installation to a Wordpress installation. I have been having problems getting the dashboard on CiviCRM to show, but I can access specific pages (such as the configuration page) by entering it directly.

In all this, I found I was getting an error in our hosting logs about accessing a directory that is no longer in use (a test directory that the new website was installed in). Upon contacting my host (Siteground) to determine what file(s) were giving that request, they recommended a plug in to Wordpress - Better Search and Replace.

I found that there were some 400 or more old links in CiviCRM tables to 'public_html/test' which was the test site. Since things are now moved to 'public_html', I changed all of those links in the database.

Now, when I click the CiviCRM link on the dashboard, I simply get "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.".

I pulled the CiviCRM logs after this found the following:

```
Jan 01 08:50:58  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => 
    [code] => 
)


Jan 01 08:50:58  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(307): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
#2 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:17))
#3 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#4 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1216): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#5 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#6 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#7 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#8 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#9 /home/nefc0709/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#10 {main}
```

If anyone has suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I usually do after migration

1. Check path and save Administer >> System Settings >> Directories.
2. Check path and save Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URL.
3. Delete template_c.
4. Rebuild menu and Trigger http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1&triggerRebuild=1
5. Run Cleanup and Cache.

(Also check if php CURL is installed on server)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Once I actually tracked down direct links to those pages, I was able to (mostly) recover things. However, it appears there was a more fundamental issue with some corrupted tables in the WP install. A new install and migration of pages/posts/etc. was done today, and I think finally all is working.